# Is there a place for a 3D modeler in 2016?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I know that this question was asked and answered hundreds of time, and I did google it and read them.The problem is that I think that 3D industry is rapidly changing. Is there place for 3D modeler in 2016?

I have strong desire to become one. I have some models, you can check them at [maxzix.cgsociety.org](http://maxzix.cgsociety.org). Do you think I should start more intensively? I am kind of lost because I am finishing high school in 5 months and there is no college for 3D in my country. I don't know what to do.

Comment: What about studying Arts? 3D-Modelling and Animation are part of Arts and many rules for Arts apply to them.

Comment: AFAIK, the Film, Gaming, Architecture, Engineering and Industrial Design industries rely heavily on 3D work.

Comment: @DA01 But in general film, gaming, and industrail design work on different technologies... So its 3 different jobs

Comment: @joojaa the conceptual/artistic/logic side is all the same, though.

Comment: @DA01 not really no.

Comment: But yes, they absolutely are different careers in many ways. I suppose film/gaming are closely related (likely go to an art school). Engineering/Architecture is more CAD related. Industrial Design is a bit of both.

Comment: @joojaa I disagree. Whether you are modeling a creature for a game or a building for an architect, you need to understand 3D concepts, illustration, lighting, colors, etc...A good CAD modeller will have some art background and a good Movie 3D modeler will have some good CAD background. But yes, both likely would come from different degree programs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33834/discussion-between-da01-and-joojaa).

Comment: Max, can you provide more details? Which country are you in? Do you know what kind of industry you'd like to work in?

Comment: I am from Croatia,Europe.Here on Art college you will learn 3D and animation for a month or two and thats 3 year college.To get on that college you need to have bunch of sketches which I do not have.As I said,I am completly lost here.There are many ways to go in cg industry.I am interested more on game assets.Example I am now modelling an zippo lighter becaouse charachter needs to light an cigar,or as I modeled an cigarete case which is needed for smoker characher.I am 18 so I dont have work experiance,sadly.

Answer (score 0):

> I have strong will becoming one

**So? Just do it!**

One thing is "modeler" one very diferent is designer. Yes probably you do not have a modeler carrer, becouse this is just a "how to use a program" issue.

Look for "Industrial Design" or "Animation" related carrers. Inclusive "Graphic design" to learn to put objetives to what you want to achive with your images.

In your portafolio I see very basic "lets copy this" models. That is totally diferent than create something new.

For "modelers" I do not there is much market. The important part are 2 things.

**1)** What can you achive with your images? How impressive they look.

**2)** How inovative the design is.

P.S. You need to learn a good render engine. Do not use that basic render you are using right now. There are some exelent free renderers. Kerkythea, LuxRender, YafRay, or inclusive Blender itself.

You can also download and use for free as a student for 3 years 3DStudio, Maya and Revit.

---

Edited:

Thinking about some coments on the chat, I remember you that there are diferent types of modeling depending on your taste or needs:

- Primitives, subdivision, sculpting, curves, etc.

And diferent fields to apicate this:

- Architecture, games, product design, advertising, movies, graphic design...

Comment: Well yeah.My models are "let's copy this" becaouse I am trying to practice 3D modelling and thats why I am modelling what I think that I can not do.When I see complicated item such as revolver,I immediatly start drawing edges on that item in my head.It is difficult to explain but any object I see,I can rotate him,move it around,zooming on smallest detail in my mind.I hope you understood.I am using 3ds max

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a good market for modeller and the needs should increase even more in the future.

I won't comment on industrial design and animation (others did and I think it's no surprise the needs are growing there too) but I'd like to mention that 3D modelling is slowly taking a great part of the photography market for some products and the next web will probably also offer more new e-commerce using that kind of technology (eg. I'm thinking more of the online clothing industry).

It's also way easier to pay to re-create a 3D model of some object and then place it in any kind of environment for "picture shooting" than actually take real pictures of that object in some cases; it's also cheaper and way more flexible.

So if what you like to do is to re-create some already existing products, I think it's possible to have a career in this and make it your specialty. You might need to focus more on some types of 3D models but with time you'll simply grow your portfolio and maybe go into the other type of 3D careers.

Comment: The reason I am recreating real life object is to get some practice.I am planning now to explore the power of renderer such as mental ray.